# Reverse edit suggestion approval/rejection

Tags: discussion, review-page

I reviewed the [suggested edit of Lauri Ranta's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34870/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-dock-in-lion/67237#67237) today, but *somehow* got distracted, and honestly didn't even pay attention to the edit enough to give it justice. I have never had this happen before but absentmindedly clicked approve. As soon as I clicked "Approve" I realized my error.

Is there a way to reverse this type of "vote"?

I understand it's not a huge deal: first, because there are more people that vote to approve/reject it, and two, rollbacks are possible, but if there is a way, I would be interested in knowing how.

Comment: FWIW - you didn't cause the edit to be approved - the first vote was for rejection, yours was the second vote and the first for approval. Another approval made the edit live. http://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the edit history allows for this quite nicely.

Click the time link to the edited by community icon and then roll back to the version you would have liked to keep.

Comment: That is a good point. Thank you. By the way, I'm curious if you happen to know how many "votes" it takes for a non-mod to approve a suggested edit? I'm guessing two or three, but not sure.

Comment: It takes two @bassplayer7 - http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/suggested-edits-now-take-more-than-one-review and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151536/it-takes-two-to-tango

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I was just about to ask if it took two of the same votes to make it live, but then saw your comment on my question. Makes sense.

Comment: The first action to gain 2 votes turns an edit suggestion into an approval or rejection.